# R library(bear) and library(reshape2) conflict in melt

Tags: r

I have the following issue when using the `bear` package in `R`:

```
origdata.wide <- read.table(header=T, text='
 subject sex control cond1 cond2
   1   M     7.9  12.3  10.7
   2   F     6.3  10.6  11.1
   3   F     9.5  13.1  13.8
   4   M    11.5  13.4  12.9
')
```

In case I only use `reshape2` this command works fine and I can use the `melt` (example taken from [R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/)).

```
 library(reshape2)
 melt(origdata.wide, id.vars=c("subject","sex"), variable.name='Condition')
```

But later I need to use the `summarySE` function, that I found out is contained in `bear`. My problem is that when I load `bear` then the `variable.name` parameter does not have any effect as well as I cannot define the table as I defined it earlier. So I think `bear` overwrites some functions. Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R will inform you if anything is overwritten. For example:

```
The following objects are masked from ‘package:plyr’:

rename, round_any
```

It seems that `bear` loads the `reshape` package which will have different arguments to those functions:

```
The following objects are masked from ‘package:reshape’:

colsplit, melt, recast
```

You can solve your problem by reloading manually, and being careful in the future to load the packages in this order:

```
 unloadNamespace('bear')
 unloadNamespace('reshape2')
 library(bear)
 library(reshape2)
```

If you see any errors of the form

```
 Error in unloadNamespace("reshape2") :
   namespace ‘reshape2’ is imported by ‘ggplot2’ so cannot be unloaded
```

then `unloadNamespace` those packages and then reload them as well. In your `~/.Rprofile` file, you can place

```
 library(bear)
 library(reshape2)
```

so that new R sessions will load correctly in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to play with the ordering, but I didn't realize, that `ggplot2` already loaded the `reshape2` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the function `melt` via the namespace `reshape2`, i.e.

```
reshape2::melt(....)
```